# Exclude Hibernate in Spring Boot not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm trying to start JUnit tests wihout hibernate. My Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, JpaBaseConfiguration.class, WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan("my.base.package")
public class TestContext {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestContext.class, args);
  }

}
```

As you can see you I excluded more and more stuff but its always the same error. My Tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestContext.class)
public class TestMail {
    @Autowired
    private Component c;

    public void setC(Component c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
       ...
    }

}
```

When I start the tests Hibernate will be configured and fails with:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "dev" are currently active).
```

So starting only the application or as context for the tests also starts hibernate configuration. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Having only:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Does not throw any exception until I try to use actual hibernate stuff. However it builds the database correctly...

EDIT2:
The problem was a custom config class that had @EnableJpaRepositories on. Also this seems not possible because Beans annotated with @Component which have autowired repositories will fail because the beans cannot be created.

Comment: As far as I understand, you should do unit testing without the Spring context and integration testing with it. Integration testing should have Hibernate enabled, but configured in a proper way (i.e. pointing to in-memory database). This points are well covered into the [integration testing](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html) part of the docs. So what you're trying to do (kind of mixture between both of them) makes little sense to me, IMHO.

Comment: Well actually there are still lots and lots of Components which do not depend on a Database. In fact the part that does depend on it is very small but all tests start a database which they should not when they don't depend on it. But I need the application context as it has many independent configurations for several Components in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class to the exclude list. This did the trick for me when I needed to exclude hibernate from the auto config.

Have you tried starting up the test with the --debug switch? That would report the auto-configuration (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html).

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Also the --debug switch doesn't seem to give me any special outputs for why or what else is configured.

Comment: I know get ```org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!```